# How to replace custom tags with HTML tags?

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace(including nested) the custom tags with HTML tags along with any text in between custom tags.

**For example:**

```
<ppbold>bold</ppbold> => <b>bold</b>
<ppitalic>bold</ppitalic> => <i>italic</i>
and so on ...
```

Please, can anyone tell the regex for that? **But keep in mind the nested tags should also be replaced properly** for example:

```
<ppbold>bold <ppitalic>bold</ppitalic></ppbold> => <b>bold<i>italic</i></b>
```

It would be good to provide the regex by using the `preg_match_all()`, `preg_match()` and `preg_replace()` functions in PHP.

Comment: What have you already tried? Show us your code.

Comment: Since this has been put on hold I can only comment, but this is some very very old code I wrote for php that does pretty much what you need. https://github.com/buggedcom/PHP-Custom-Tags

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`preg_replace_callback()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) here with

```
~(</?)(\w+)(>)~
```

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

$string = "<ppbold>bold <ppitalic>bold</ppitalic></ppbold>";

$replacements = ["ppbold" => "b", "ppitalic" => "i"];

$regex = "~(</?)(\w+)(>)~";
$string = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($match) use ($replacements) {
        return $match[1] . $replacements[$match[2]] . $match[3];
    },
    $string
);

echo $string;
?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/kxNZd4) and on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aoGdAk/1) for the expression.